# Update on Android api level 8.1

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I am fetching the files from downloads using"getProvidersDownloadsData" its working fine till android 8 but in Android 8.1 the file path is coming null and getting crash.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Use android.support.v4.content.FileProvider to get path for download file.